# Table Auto TR Count

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this Table + this JS Script that I use. 
I want to add an auto TR counter at in the left side TD that is empty. 
So when I add a column it will auto count up and for example, I have 100 columns, when I delete the 35 column, the number should go down

```js
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
  myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 3000);
}

function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.buttons').on('click', 'button.hide', function() {
    console.log('hide');
    $('form').hide();
  });

  $('.buttons').on('click', 'button.add', function() {
    console.log('add');
    var edit = $('#edit');
    editRow = $('#editRow');

    edit.show();
    if (!($('#addNew').length)) {
      edit.append('<input type="button" id="addNew" onclick="addNewTr()" value="Add" name="submit" />');
    }

    if (editRow) {
      editRow.remove();
    }

    for (var x = 1; x < $('input').length; x++) {
      $('#btd' + x).val('');
    }
  });

  $('#show').click(function() {
    //$('form').show();
    //$('#btd1').val('Vlad');
    //$('#btd2').val('Andrei');
    //$('#btd3').val('vTask');
    //  $('#btd4').val('Ceva');
    //$('#btd5').val('Alceva');
  });
});

function edit(a) {
  var edit = $('#edit');
  addNew = $('#addNew');
  editRow = $('#editRow');

  edit.show();
  if (addNew) {
    addNew.remove();
  }

  if (editRow.length) {
    editRow.replaceWith('<input type="button" id="editRow" onclick="save(' + a + ')" value="Submit" name="submit" />');
  } else {
    edit.append('<input type="button" id="editRow" onclick="save(' + a + ')" value="Submit" name="submit" />');
  }

  $.each($('.tr-' + a).find('td'), function(key, val) {
    $('form#edit input[type=text]').eq(key).val($(val).text());
  });
}

function save(a) {
  var tr = $('tr');
  valid = true;
  message = '';

  $('form#edit input').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if (!$this.val()) {
      var inputName = $this.attr('name');
      valid = false;
      message += 'Please complete all the colums' + inputName + '\n';
    }
  });

  if (!valid) {
    alert(message);
  } else {
    for (var q = 1; q < $('.tr-' + a + ' td').length; q++) {
      $('.tr-' + a + ' td:nth-child(' + q + ')').html($('#btd' + q).val());
    }
    for (var x = 1; x < $('input').length; x++) {
      $('#btd' + x).val('');
    }
    $('#editRow').remove();
  }
}

function addNewTr() {
  var tr = $('tr');
  valid = true;
  message = '';

  $('form#edit input').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if (!$this.val()) {
      var inputName = $this.attr('name');
      valid = false;
      message += 'Please enter your ' + inputName + '\n';
    }
  });

  if (!valid) {
    alert(message);
  } else {
    $('table tbody').append('' +
      '<tr class="tr-' + tr.length + '">' +
      '<td>' + $('#btd1').val() + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + $('#btd2').val() + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + $('#btd3').val() + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + $('#btd4').val() + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + $('#btd5').val() + '</td>' +
      '<td class="buttons">' +
      '<button class="removeThis" onclick="removeThis(' + tr.length + ')">Delete</button >' +
      '<button class="edit" onclick="edit(' + tr.length + ')">Edit</button >' +
      '</td >' +
      '</tr>' +
      '');
    for (var x = 1; x < $('input').length; x++) {
      $('#btd' + x).val('');
    }
  }
}

function removeThis(a) {
  $('.tr-' + a).remove();
}

$('.addRow').on('click', function() {
  addRow();
});

var i = 1;

function addRow() {
  var tr = '<tr>' +
    '<td>' + i + '</td>' +
    '</tr>';
  $('tbody').append(tr);
  i++;
};
```

```css
/* Center the loader */

#loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border: 16px solid #e80041;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #188f84;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}


/* Add animation to "page content" */

.animate-bottom {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatebottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: animatebottom;
  animation-duration: 1s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatebottom {
  from {
    bottom: -100px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    bottom: 0px;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes animatebottom {
  from {
    bottom: -100px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

#myDiv {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Top Header */

#hh1 {
  color: #1b998b;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Sans-serif;
}

#vt1 {
  color: White;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* BODY */

body {
  background-color: #999da5;
}

table.greenTable {
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  border: 6px solid #152842;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  width: 70%;
  text-align: center;
}

table.greenTable td,
table.greenTable th {
  border: 4px solid #1F6698;
  padding: 3px 2px;
}

table.greenTable tbody td {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

table.greenTable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #999DA5;
}

table.greenTable thead {
  background: #93B5C1;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #aec7d0 0%, #9dbcc7 66%, #93B5C1 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #aec7d0 0%, #9dbcc7 66%, #93B5C1 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #aec7d0 0%, #9dbcc7 66%, #93B5C1 100%);
  border-bottom: 0px solid #444444;
}

table.greenTable thead th {
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #F0F0F0;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 2px solid #1B998B;
}

table.greenTable thead th:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

table.greenTable tfoot td {
  font-size: 13px;
}

table.greenTable tfoot .links {
  text-align: right;
}

table.greenTable tfoot .links a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


/* BUTTONS */


/* BODY */

button {
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000 !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #152842;
  background: #63B8EE;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #1F6698, #1B998B);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1F6698, #1B998B);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#1F6698), to(#1B998B));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1F6698, #1B998B);
}

button:hover {
  color: #14396A !important;
  background: #468CCF;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #93B5C1, #D1D1D1);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #93B5C1, #D1D1D1);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#93B5C1), to(#D1D1D1));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #93B5C1, #D1D1D1);
}

#addNew {
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000 !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 1px 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #152842;
  background: #63B8EE;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #1F6698, #1B998B);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1F6698, #1B998B);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#1F6698), to(#1B998B));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1F6698, #1B998B);
}

#addNew:hover {
  color: #14396A !important;
  background: #468CCF;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #93B5C1, #D1D1D1);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #93B5C1, #D1D1D1);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#93B5C1), to(#D1D1D1));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #93B5C1, #D1D1D1);
}

#editRow {
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000 !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 1px 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #152842;
  background: #63B8EE;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #1F6698, #1B998B);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1F6698, #1B998B);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#1F6698), to(#1B998B));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1F6698, #1B998B);
}

#editRow:hover {
  color: #14396A !important;
  background: #468CCF;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #93B5C1, #D1D1D1);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #93B5C1, #D1D1D1);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#93B5C1), to(#D1D1D1));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #93B5C1, #D1D1D1);
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.read-more {
  background: #222;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 6px #eee;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 6px #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 6px #eee;
}

.read-more:before {
  content: "<<";
  color: #fff;
}

#content {
  color: #222;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 30%;
  margin: 200px auto 0;
  padding: 50px;
  border: 4px solid #222;
}

#preloader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #222222;
  z-index: 99999;
  height: 100%;
}

#status {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  margin: -32px 0 0 -32px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body onload="myFunction()" style="margin:0;">
  <div id="loader"></div>
  <div style="display:none;" id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
    <h1 id="hh1">[<a id="vt1">vTask</a>]</h1>

    <table class="greenTable" id="myTable">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="6">
            <form id="edit" action="" method="post" hidden>
              <label for="btd1"></label >
      <input type="text" name="Name" id="btd1" value="" placeholder="Name">
  <label for="btd2" ></label >
      <input type="text" name="Secondary Name" id="btd2" value="" placeholder="Secondary Name">
  <label for="btd3" ></label >
      <input type="text" name="Email" id="btd3" value="" placeholder="Email">
  <label for="btd4" ></label >
      <input type="text" name="Telephone" id="btd4" value="" placeholder="Telephone">
  <label for="btd5" ></label >
      <input type="text" name="Password" id="btd5" value="" placeholder="Password">
  </form ></td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  <td width="10%">Password</td>
  <td width="10%">Name</td>
  <td width="10%">Secondary Name</td>
  <td width="10%">Email</td>
  <td width="10%">Telephone</td>
  <td class="buttons" width="20%"><button class="add" >Add</button >
  <button class="hide" >Hide</button >
  </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table >
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me. At the bottom of the script I have a counter based on TBody but it's not working

Comment: simply loop all the `td` wich jquery `$.each()` and then increase the a counter like `$i++`.. you know, the usual counter/loop?

Comment: Sorry I don't. Started learning JS 2 weeks ago

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Demo. I fire it document ready function. You can change firing status however you want. it may be onkeyup, onclik etc. Just fire the function and it counts then tell your the number.

[**Here You GO**](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=2a79ec8e340deaf69b2998e05c571455)

Comment: Check The link again and you are good to go. Actually the code i wrote is working for you but you could not bind it to your firing action. I did it and bind it to add button. and also delete as well to count after removal. The name of the function is Counter. You can check the code its in your js

Comment: Yea it counts but the counter remains in the empty TD. When I add another TR that TD doesn't exist so the counter goes there

Comment: Btw, you using input type=text for all of them. You should use password for passwords and email for emails.

Comment: well there is a loop on that type=text so it's hard to start rewriting the code

Comment: Check the code now. I belive you are good to go. Simply i defined a var m = 1; and everytime i add the line number i did m++ and in removal function i added m--. So it works as you wish i belive

Comment: Countdown doesn't go down in my index file.

Comment: I created 5 new TR and I deleted the third one. Number 3 goes at the first TR and the countdown doesn't go down it remains 5-4-2-1-3

Comment: You have used so many different undepended vars in so many function which is making it diffecult to catch whats goin on. I fixed the bug you told but now when you remove few of them and add new your tr.length value gives same class with other and on clicking remove others being removed too. you need to rewrite all your js with better format and vars and instead of using incremeneted classes use 'this' to referans that. Classes is for common elements to change them all or manipulate them all, not each one different from eachother.

Comment: well, I have 2 weeks of javascript learning so that would take some time for me to rewrite all of it. Il try and see how to do it

Comment: You learn it as you write and you get better everytime you start with a new page. Now you will be write it more regular.

Comment: Yea. But I'm still searching for a professor to teach me cuz what I made here is something that someone requested me to do that already know his stuff. But he can't teach me any more right now so I have to find someone else